# Convert jQuery code into javascript depending html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html and js code. But the javascript code is by jQuery and I want to convert this jQuery code to Javascript:

```js
// jquery code
$('.hello[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   $(this).siblings('.hello[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

and my html markup:

```html
<div>
    <span>Group 1:</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="group1 hello" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="group1 hello" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="group1 hello" />
</div>

<div>
    <span>Group 2:</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="group2 hello" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="group2 hello" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="group2 hello" />
</div>

<div>
    <span>Group 3:</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="group3 hello" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="group3 hello" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="group3 hello" />
</div>
```

i want to use this code for check box input that i want to checked only one input by user

[view demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tnh5r9zb/1/)

i try this code by changing and add attribute in html but it don`t work properly for group in the my questin

```js
function checkOnlyOne(b){

var x = document.getElementsByClassName('daychecks');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if(x[i].value != b) x[i].checked = false;
}
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>Group 3:</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="group3 hello" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value); />
    <input type="checkbox" class="group3 hello" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value); />
    <input type="checkbox" class="group3 hello" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value); />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method to get elements using CSS selector.

```js
// jquery code
document.querySelectorAll('.hello[type="checkbox"]').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.hello[type="checkbox"]').forEach(el1 => {
      if (el !== el1) el1.checked = false;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Group 1:</span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="group1 hello" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="group1 hello" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="group1 hello" />
</div>

<div>
  <span>Group 2:</span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="group2 hello" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="group2 hello" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="group2 hello" />
</div>

<div>
  <span>Group 3:</span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="group3 hello" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="group3 hello" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="group3 hello" />
</div>
```

---

***FYI :*** You can achieve the same behaviour with radio button without any additional Javascript code, Just need to provide same name attribute for a group.

```html
<div>
  <span>Group 1:</span>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" class="group1 hello" />
  <input type="radio" name="group1" class="group1 hello" />
  <input type="radio" name="group1" class="group1 hello" />
</div>
```